# Newsletter tool

Tags: newsletter

I want to set up a newsletter tool on my own server to send mails to 6000 subscribers. First i wanted to use mailman3 for that case, but I am not very sure if its convenient enough to use. So I would like to know if there is a good alternative, or is it even smart to set this up on your own server or should I better use services like mailchimp? I would like not to because I would like to keep the data on my own servers and I hope 6000 subscribers are not that much.

Comment: we won't help for coding questions

Comment: why coding? I am looking for a tool

Comment: It's not clear what you want but you can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and cron job on your own server otherwise Incredimail, Mozilla Thunderbird or Outlook should work. What kind of server do you have, php or asp? Do you have price limitation?

Comment: it looks like Mailtrain is what I was looking for